# Null pointer excpetion on intent creation

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I've got an error I've never had before : when I'm using the following

```
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Research.class);
```

I've got a NullPointerException... But Research.class is not null and "this" neighter... But Research class is in a different package, is it problematic ? Different package but same projet.

My stack trace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135) 
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)  
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3491) 
at mypackage.Connect.disconnect(Connect.java:92), and line 92 is the one I posted.
```

I've well imported the class needed for the intent and it's declared in the manifest.xml.

Comment: post. stack. trace.

Comment: You try for this Intent intent = new Intent(this, Research.class);

Comment: My stack trace : java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3491)
at mypackage.Connect.disconnect(Connect.java:92), and line 92 is the one I posted

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Research.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

import that package also in your activity.

```
import com.anotherpackage.*;
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, Research.class);           
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I've already imported the good package, but I still have the problem, even with that writing. Plan B ?

Answer (score 1):

I have Two package

1. `com.example.testapp` is my `main Package`

in this i have `MainActivity`

2 - I have another Package name `com.example.main.util`

in this i have `testActivity`

---

so in android manifest i add like:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.main.util.testActivity" >
```

now i have to call `testActivity` from `MainActivity` then i write:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, testActivity.class));
```

Comment: I've added the activity in the manifest already, still have the problem (even with that writing for startActivity).